# How To Copy Values Only From File (not format, formulas, etc.)

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy data values only without the format. How do I do this?

My existing code below copies the format.

```
wbkSource_Feeder.Worksheets(1).Activate
sourceColCount = wbkSource_Feeder.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
For Each Cell In wbkSource_Feeder.Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, sourceColCount))
wbkDest.Worksheets("sheet2").Activate
destColCount = wbkDest.Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
For Each Cell2 In wbkDest.Worksheets("sheet2").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, destColCount))
    If Cell = Cell2 Then
        Set DestRng = wbkDest.Worksheets("sheet2").Range(Cells(Cell2.Offset(1, 0).Row, Cell2.Column), Cells(SourceLastRow, Cell2.Column))
        wbkSource_Feeder.Worksheets(1).Activate
       wbkSource_Feeder.Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(Cell.Offset(1, 0).Row, Cell.Column), Cells(SourceLastRow, Cell.Column)).Copy Destination:=DestRng
    Exit For
    End If
Next Cell2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Set Value approach shown below. This should work more efficiently for you.

```
destrng.Value = wbkSource_Feeder.Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(Cell.Offset(1, 0).Row, Cell.Column), Cells(SourceLastRow, Cell.Column))
```

Or here is how to do exactly what you want:

```
   wbkSource_Feeder.Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(Cell.Offset(1, 0).Row, Cell.Column), Cells(SourceLastRow, Cell.Column)).Copy
   destRNG.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

A couple of friendly suggestions (just to add a little more value to this short answer):

- Define your variables, particular ranges (i.e. `Dim destRNG as Range`). It will allow you to [see the variable properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4eVhe.jpg) with intellisense.
- I don't think you need to use `Activate` as most of your code specifies the sheet.
- Using [With](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/using-with-statements) to avoid having to type out a lot of those definitions.
- When referencing the sheet, don't use the sheet display name (i.e. "Sheet2"). Try to reference the technical ID in case some [crazy user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sObBn.jpg) changes the tab name.

Good luck.